# Trouble Connecting Scrapy Pipeline to Firestore DB

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm a Python NOOB trying to write Scrapy results to Firebase Firestore using Python 3. Spider results are logging correctly to the console, but I can't seem to write to my Firestore DB. Any help is greatly appreciated.

ERROR Message:

```
db = firestore.client()
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.firestore' has no attribute 'client'
```

Pipeline File:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
from google.cloud import firestore
    
    
    class DataProcessPipeline:
    
        def __init__(self):
            cred = credentials.Certificate('./serviceAccountKey.json')
            firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,
                {
                  'databaseURL': 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com'
                }
            )
    
        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            db = firestore.client()
            doc_ref = db.collection('f1_articles')
            doc_ref.add(item.to_dict())
            # doc_ref.insert(dict(item))
            return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo `Client()` instead of `client()` :

```py
db = firestore.Client()
```

From the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/):

```py
from google.cloud import firestore

# Add a new document
db = firestore.Client()
doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'alovelace')
doc_ref.set({
    u'first': u'Ada',
    u'last': u'Lovelace',
    u'born': 1815
})

# Then query for documents
users_ref = db.collection(u'users')

for doc in users_ref.stream():
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
i am getting this error, though my json file is in the same location as pipelines.py